# How to make a VirtualBox window go to fullscreen mode from python?

Tags: python, fullscreen, virtualbox, sendkeys, win32com

I am working with the VirtualBox python API and am trying to open a VM window in fullscreen mode. I have been unable to find an API command to do so, so I am trying to use the win32api to send a keyboard command of F8+f (F8 is my host key since there is no SendKeys code for Right Control) to the application, but am not succeeding in this endeavor. My code follows, any ideas?

```
import time,win32api,win32con,win32com
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
#The title of the application was copied from the Task Manager
shell.AppActivate("fed (Snapple) [Running] - Oracle VM VirtualBox")
win32api.Sleep(100)
shell.SendKeys("({F8}f)")
```

Comment: Have a look at [VirtualBox's official Python API](https://blogs.oracle.com/nike/entry/python_api_to_the_virtualbox). (This is a comment because I don't have time to look up how to do the specific thing you're asking for right now.)

Answer (score 0):

> hey check this out ..may be it helps you..
>
> This is pyVBOX, a shim layer above the VirtualBox Python API.
>
> Why? Becuase the VirtualBox Python API is somewhat complex and I got
>   tried of trying to remember all the details of its use. Plus it
>   changes from release to release and this gives me an abstraction layer
>   to hide those changes. The software also includes a script,
>   utils/pyVbox.py, that provides the ability to manipulate VMs (like
>   VBoxMange).
>
> This code is written to the 4.1 version of VirtualBox (4.1.12
>   specifically). I have not tried it against any other version.
>
> This software is independently created from VirtualBox and Oracle. No
>   endorsement by Oracle or the VirtualBox authors is implied.
>
> [pyVbox](https://github.com/von/pyVBox)